# How to write app-specific data to device's file storage with app-only access permissions

Tags: ios, icloud, file-permissions, nsfilemanager

I want to write data to the device's file storage in a given folder such that the files in that folder are not accessible to the device owner browsing file storage nor to any other app on the device and nor is it backed up as part of iCloud or any other such service.

Is the code below correct for achieving this? Specifically, is the "Application Support" directory with the "User Domain" mask the correct place to save these files? Do I need to set specific permissions on the individual files that guarantees their limited visibility? Do I need to specify for each file individually to be excluded from backup services?

```
NSString* bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *urls = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                    inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

NSURL *url = [urls objectAtIndex:0];

url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:bundleIdentifier];
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];

if (![url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:nil]) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtURL:url
          withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                           attributes:nil
                                error:nil];

    [url setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                   forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                    error:nil];
}

url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.txt"];

[@"MyString" writeToURL:url
             atomically:YES
               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                  error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Enable `Data Protection` capability in your application. Data protection enhances the built-in hardware encryption by protecting the hardware encryption keys with your passcode. This provides an additional layer of protection for your email messages attachments, and third-party applications.

You can encrypt complete app data by enabling `data protection` in your provisioning profile or file by file like below.....

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[self filePath]
                          contents:[@"super secret file contents"
                 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                        attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete
                                                               forKey:NSFileProtectionKey]];
```

Comment: From what I understand `NSFileProtectionComplete` only applies if the device has a passcode set... is that correct? If so, this is not a solution that guarantees protected storage.

Comment: iReddy, see question here: [What exactly does *NSFileProtectionComplete* mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454173/what-exactly-does-nsfileprotectioncomplete-mean)