# What exactly does *NSFileProtectionComplete* mean?

Tags: ios, file-permissions, nsfilemanager

I'm looking at the [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html) class reference and I'm a bit confused by what `NSFileProtectionComplete` means. This is what the class reference says:

> The file is stored in an encrypted format on disk and cannot be read
>   from or written to while the device is locked or booting.

Does this mean that the file is stored in encrypted format on disk *always*... regardless of whether the device has a passcode (or similar security mechanism) set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## complete protection

(NSFileProtectionComplete): The class key is protected with a key derived from the user's passcode and the UID of the device. Shortly after the lock a device by the user (after 10 seconds when "Request code"> "Ready"), the decrypted class key is discarded, so that all data of this class are inaccessible until the user enters the code again or unlock the device with touch ID.

Q: GERMAN https://www.apple.com/de/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

=> so the decryption key is only valid while the device remains unlocked

Comment: Thanks. So the data is encrypted only when the device is locked or booting. That makes sense.

Comment: English version of the attached doc, https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf